# Can not share DVD drive from one Macbook Pro to another

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, dvd

I don't know the specifics of CD/DVD drive sharing on OS X, but my understanding is the following:

I have two Macbook Pros, one late-2007 with a damaged DVD drive and one early-2011 with a fully functioning one. When I turn on CD/DVD drive sharing on the new one, isn't the older one supposed to display the shared drive in the finder?

My problem is: **I am not able to access the drive, I just can't see it in the Finder's sidebar.**

Some additional info:

- Both are running 10.6.6
- Both are in the same network, subnet and are able to see each other
- I **need** the DVD inserted to install the software, it won't install from a mounted .iso or .dmg file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disk Sharing (client-side) is only enabled for [Macbook Air and certain Mac minis](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1777?viewlocale=en_US):

> You can then share CDs or DVDs from your Mac or PC **to your MacBook Air or Mac mini** via your network.

There's a hidden preference to enable it though. Enter the following in *Terminal*:

```
defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser EnableODiskBrowsing -bool true
defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser ODSSupported -bool true
```

Reboot and you can start using it on your broken MBP.